# Setup domain name on VPS with full root access

Tags: dns, vps, nameservers

My first question ever. and newbie to webhosting.
I am trying navicosoft.com vps for the first time for webhosting. VPS just had centOS 7 on it. I installed ruby rails apache passenger etc and deployed my app. App deployed successfully. Here is the IP address http://88.198.121.97/ (site is still in production mode though). I also purchased domain dogtags.pk from http://pknic.net with its nameservers ns1.navicosoft.com | ns2.navicosoft.com. It has been over 72 hours since i registered for the domain.

I want to know what am I doing wrong? why is my site accessible via IP address and not  by domain name? If i can get some link to a tutorial or documentation of some kind.

Customer support is very crappy. They are saying we dont provide any technical help for VPS. Help please. Thanks.

Comment: If that's the response you got from their support, take it as a hint and move to a better VPS before it's too late. For example, Digital Ocean provides a better VPS than navicosoft at 1/3rd the cost. They also have great documentation for issues like this one. Do you want a $10 credit to try it out?

Comment: Ok they just replied again saying "You have to setup your own dns in your vps and those dns you have to update in your domain to use that with your hositng"

Comment: @kul ... yea u are right.... i have tried digital ocean its much better and easier. but unfortunately for now i will have to stick to it.

Comment: Any documentation or tutorial on setting up dns on vps?

Comment: Which control panel do you have? If it's a custom one then only your host can guide you through the process. I tried looking through their documentation but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

The best way might be to use a free DNS service (https://www.google.com/search?q=free+dns+service).

The setup would be as follows:

1. Use a free DNS service to point your domain name to the correct IP address.
2. Modify your domain name's nameservers to those of the free DNS service provider you've chosen.

For example, here's a link to how you can set this up with Namecheap's FreeDNS service: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/536/51/how-do-i-set-my-domain-to-use-namecheaps-freedns-service

Comment: Thanks for the reply. navicosoft only allows that for shared hosting. for VPS they are saying I will have to setup my own dns on vps and setup domain name servers. (probably this means i will not be using ns1 and ns2.navicosoft.com ...still not sure though)

Comment: Updated the answer with a better alternative given that you can't use your host's DNS servers.